# How to know how many video cards a computer has?

Tags: graphics

I have a laptop with radeon graphic card, but I am not sure of the  number of video cards it has. How to know it?

I run `lspci -nn | grep '\[03'` and got:

```
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Intel Corporation Haswell-ULT Integrated Graphics Controller [8086:0a16] (rev 09)
0a:00.0 Display controller [0380]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Sun XT [Radeon HD 8670A/8670M/8690M / R5 M330] [1002:6660] (rev ff)
```

What does it mean?

Comment: Run `lspci -nn | grep '\[03'` in a terminal.

Comment: Now you have the answer right there in the question :)

Comment: @P.-H.Lin i put the output on my question, so how many do i have?

Comment: You have 2 video adapters, isn't it clear from the output?

Comment: It is strange that they are not equal. I thought that if i had 2, they would be equal.

Comment: Can i do multiseat with those 2 video cards?

Comment: What do you mean by "equal"?

Comment: Most likely you can't use them as separate video adapters. But it is a different issue.

Comment: @Pilot6, i mean by equal that according to my output, i have an intel video card and a radeon video card. So they seem that cant be used separately, because I want to do a multiseat.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run `lspci -nn | grep '\[03'`.

The output it generated in your case, as posted in your question, means you have 2 video cards.